# Redirect on Permission Error Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

## Issue

Accessing a page without permission gives the error message:

> You do not have permission to view this resource. Please contact the Site Administrator.

However, it should instead redirect to `/login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Joomla Solution

Set the permission of the given menu item to Registered, and anyone who is not will be redirected to your login page.

## Code Solution:

If you want to break the rules and implement this with code, you can add the following code into your template:

```
if ($('.cAlert:contains("You do not have permission to view this resource.")').length) {
    window.location.href = "/login";
};
```

Comment: Done. Thanks for the advice.